# Can I comment out Thread ID or Threading Token?

Tags: email, servicecloud

I'm not a huge fan of either the Thread ID or Threading Token sitting in full visibility of recipients, either in the body or the subject. My question is if I wished to include it to ensure emails are threaded to the right case, can I also comment it out in HTML ()?

I believe I read somewhere in the documentation that salesforce will scan html for mention of the thread ID if it can't find it in the Subject or Body, but I'm not certain if it works on commented html. Also, can the Threading Token be referenced via a merge field similar to Thread ID?

If there are any other suggestions on how to hide it while making use of it, I'd love to know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Thread ID ("Ref ID"). You can now use the [New Threading Behavior for Email-To-Case](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389648&type=1), which uses the `Message-ID` header for case threading. Most, if not all, mail clients will automatically include the `Message-ID` (which is how "conversations" work in Outlook, Gmail, etc), so it is managed by email metadata instead of any string in the subject or body. Read [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.support_email_to_case_threading.htm&type=5) for more information on the different modes of threading, how you can use new methods to determine how to thread cases in Apex, etc. As far as hiding the Ref ID in HTML, you *should* be able to, but that would be an inferior method to just using the new header-based setting.

Comment: The article you shared mentioned Token based being the new behavior (for Lightning Threading). How reliable is the Message-ID (header) fallback method if I opted to exclude the Token as well? This is assuming all my email-to-case configs are set to save header info.

Comment: @Iamgnee - my experience with the Message-Id threading is that it is not 100% reliable (duplicate cases can get created; I've also seen emails attached to the wrong case). The Token was introduced (Spring 23) to (hopefully) fix these issues

Comment: @cropredy So in other words, they went from a Thread_Id which would put in to the email subject/body, switched to message header threading, that didn't work, so they're going back to Thread_Tokens which is basically Thread_Id again? Salesforce is one of the most inept companies I've ever seen.